# Parse Value to Int, String, UInt, etc. Based on Selected Item in ComboBox

Tags: c#, parsing, if-statement, combobox, textbox

I'm just posting mostly to see if there is a better way to do this. My biggest pet peeve in C# is definitely the excessive overuse of If statements to determine what function should be executed ie:

```
if (comboBoxEdit1.Text == "Soup")

else if (comboBoxEdit1.Text == "Salad")
//Continues on for 10 more statements
```

So what I am wondering is if it is possible for me to determine how I should parse a certain value inside of a textbox, based on what is selected index of my combobox is. 
ie: comboBox is Int32

```
Int32.TryParse(textEdit1.Text, out i);
```

Is the best way really to use the if statements? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Full Code

```
//Convert.To(x) depends on combo box
    searchVal = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToUInt32(searchBox.Text));
                toGet = (uint)searchVal.Length;

for (uint i = 0; i <= memSize/toGet; i++)
            {
                uint address = startAddress + (i * toGet);
                byte[] recoveredMem = XboxSupport.GetMem(address, toGet);
if (recoveredMem == searchVal)
                    {
                        if (valType == "UInt32")
                        {
                            uint val = BitConverter.ToUInt32(recoveredMem, 0);
                            siInfo.Caption = String.Format("{0} Found At Address: {1}", val, String.Format("0x" + String.Format("{0:X}", address)));
                            File.AppendAllText(path, String.Format("0x" + String.Format("{0:X}", address) + " | {0}", "{1}", val, Environment.NewLine));
                        }
    }
```

Basic Summary of Code: 
Recovers memory from a specific block, determined by the user, and searches that area for a value they would like to find during run time, then compiles a list of the search results inside a text file.

Comment: What are you doing inside if statements?

Comment: I Hope you send full code to understand your issue

Comment: There is nothing new or C# specific with your "excessive overuse of If statements" - there are well known ways to deal with it like http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html and http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithVisitor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a `switch` - `case` might help. Instead of using all the 'if' statements, you can use the switch statement. Here's an example:

```
switch(comboBox1.Text)
{
    case "Soup":
        //Function
        break;

    case "Salad":
    case "AnotherItem":
        //Do Something
        break;

    case "AnotherAnotherItem":
        //Do Something else
        break;

default:
    //Not specified.
    break;
}
```

Would that help? In each case you can choose do a specific function, etc.

Comment: +1. This is an option, also most likely more refactoring would be needed to remove conditionals altogether.

Comment: I have seen this before, definitely might be the best way to do it. I'll see if any other ideas are suggested but this is absolutely a feasible solution